# How can I prevent typescript from complaining that a property can be undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, interface

I am writing an expressjs/typescript backend API. I am making helper function (used in a decorator) for checking authentication data. It accepts `IMyRequest` data and does some checks and returns it as `IMyAuthenticatedRequest`.

But for some reason, typescript still complains about the `req` parameter in the return statement of the `authenticate` function that req.user may be undefined, even though I tested (and threw an error) if it is. How do I prevent this error?

This is the error:

```
Type 'IMyRequest' is not assignable to type 'IMyAuthenticatedRequest'.
Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
Type 'IUserRequestData | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IUserRequestData'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IUserRequestData'.
```

This is sample code that typescript complains about (about the return statement on the second to last line):

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

interface IUserRequestData {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  company: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  };
}

interface IAuthenticatedHeaders {
  authorization: string;
  [x: string]: any;
}

interface IMyRequest extends Request {
  user?: IUserRequestData;
  correlationId?: any;
}

interface IMyAuthenticatedRequest extends IMyRequest {
  user: IUserRequestData;
  headers: IAuthenticatedHeaders;
}

interface IAuthenticationResult {
  req: IMyAuthenticatedRequest;
  res: Response;
  user: IUserRequestData;
  authenticated: boolean;
  authorization: string;
}

export function authenticate(req: IMyRequest, res: Response): IAuthenticationResult {
  /**
   * Check the authorization information on the request object and return it.
   *
   * @param args
   */

  if (!req.user || !req.headers || !req.headers.authorization) {
    throw new Error('Authentication error');
  }

  const { authorization } = req.headers;

  return { req, res, authorization, user: req.user, authenticated: true };
}
```

Comment: Did the below answer your question? Need any more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use type guard function

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

interface IUserRequestData {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  company: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  };
}

interface IAuthenticatedHeaders {
  authorization: string;
  [x: string]: any;
}

interface IMyRequest extends Request {
  user?: IUserRequestData;
  correlationId?: any;
}

interface IMyAuthenticatedRequest extends IMyRequest {
  user: IUserRequestData;
  headers: IAuthenticatedHeaders;
}

interface IAuthenticationResult {
  req: IMyAuthenticatedRequest;
  res: Response;
  user: IUserRequestData;
  authenticated: boolean;
  authorization: string;
}

export function authenticate(
  req: IMyRequest,
  res: Response
): IAuthenticationResult {
  /**
   * Check the authorization information on the request object and return it.
   *
   * @param args
   */

  isAthenticationRequest(req);

  const { authorization } = req.headers;

  return { req, res, authorization, user: req.user, authenticated: true };
}

function isAthenticationRequest(
  req: IMyAuthenticatedRequest | IMyRequest
): asserts req is IMyAuthenticatedRequest {
  if (!req.user || !req.headers || !req.headers.authorization) {
    throw new Error("Authentication error");
  }
}
```